# execvp() not processing writing to output >filename.log

Tags: c, linux, exec

I have some problem with execvp in my code, I want to write a simple terminal which save the result of command in log file, the problem is that when I use `"> a.log"` which should bring the result to the output, it is not responding and goes to error!

```
int lsh_launch(char **args)
{
pid_t pid;
int status;
int i = 0;
while (args[i] != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", args[i]);
    i++;
}
args[i] = ">";
args[i + 1] = "a.log";
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    printf("child proc\n");
    // Child process
    if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
    {
    perror("lsh");
    }
    if (execvp(args[0], args)  == -1)
    {
    perror("lsh");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if (pid < 0)
{
    // Error forking
    perror("lsh");
}
else
{
    // Parent process
    do {
    waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
}
return 1;
}
```

When I change args with other value (for example `-v` to see the version) it works, and it seems the problem is with exporting to output! the result when I do `ls` and `> a.log` with program is:

```
-  ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
-  ls: cannot access a.log: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirections are not obtained this way. `>` (or similar) is a syntax to make redirection in a shell. The shell interprets the command line and make redirections before `exec`ing the command, this way :

```
pid = fork();
switch(pid) {
case 0:
  d = open("myfile",O_WRONLY);
  dup2(d,STDOUT_FILENO); // redirect *stdout* to open file d by duplicating it
  close(d); // now unused d (d is a duplicate of *stdout*
  exec**(...); // now mutate to a new code which inherits open file descriptors
  exit(1);
  break;
case -1: // error case of fork
  break;
default:
  wait(NULL); // or whatever you want, don't wait for *background style*
  break;
}
```

Comment: Nice ... So much better to use a `switch`! but also see my answer, there is yet a more fundamental problem. Although your answer actually answers the *actual* question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `args` is the `argv` passed to the `main()` function<sup>1</sup>:

Your program invokes *Undefined Behavior*

```
while (args[i] != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", args[i]);
    i++;
}
```

At the end of this loop, `i` has a value beyond the bounds of the `args` array. Thus

```
args[i] = ">";
args[i + 1] = "a.log";
```

tries to write there at the forbidden location, invoking undefined behavior.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It's not clear because apparently some code is missing</sub>